# create the variable for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create the variable to get the list of values from the list.

When I try this:

```
test = [posX for pos_X in posX]
print test
```

I will get this like 100 times:

```
['375', '609', '733', '1481', '2514', '2580', '5893', '8123', '8645', '9344', '9866', '10215', '10737', '11086', '11260', '11609', '12131', '12653', '13175', '13697', '14219', '14568', '14917', '15266', '15615', '15964', '16997', '17346', '17520', '17869', '18443', '18509', '22506', '24736', '25258', '25957', '26479', '26828', '27350', '27699', '27873', '28222', '28744', '29266', '29788', '30310', '30832', '31181', '31530', '31879', '32228', '32927', '33626', '33975', '34149', '35011', '35077', '39131', '41361', '41883', '42582', '43104', '43453', '43975', '44324', '44498', '44847', '45369', '45891', '46413', '46935']
```

Can you please help me with how I can print the list of values using the variable that I created with the for loop inside the variable?

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong variable names: test = [pos_X for pos_X in posX]

Comment: Do `[pos_X for pos_X in posX]`.

Comment: @qwertyuip9 what is the correct variable name i should use to print the list of each value?

Comment: Basically, using [pos_X for pos_X in posX] rather than [posX for pos_X in posX] since posX appears to be your list while pos_X is a temporary variable that will reference each element in posX

Comment: @qwertyuip9 thank you very much for this, but when I try to use `print pos_X`, it will print the list. How i can print for each value from the list using print `pos_X`?

Comment: @user3788310: if I understood correctly, a for loop iterating across your list should print out the answer. You could potentially do this `[print(posX) for pos_X in posX]` if `posX` is your list although the for loop would be easier to read compared to a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That comprehension is creating a `list` where every element points to the entire original `list`, for every element in that original `list`. You might have wanted `[pos_X for pos_X in posX]` (note `pos_X` with an underscore rather than `posX`), although that just creates a shallow copy of `posX` and isn't really necessary if all you want to do is print `posX`. Just use a traditional loop:

```
for element in posX:
    print element
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is on how to display values in a list. If not please provide your input and expected output

```
>>> my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> print my_list
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for val in my_list:
...     print val
...
1
2
3
4
5
6
>>>
```

The code what you wrote

```
[posX for pos_x in posX]
```

say posX is a list which has 100 elements in it, then posX will be it iterates 100 times and duplicates posX.

The code actually is same as

```
 >>> posX
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 >>> check=[]
 >>>for posx in pos_X:
        check.append(pos_X )
 >>> check
  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```